# Sorting an array with a compare function - javascript

Tags: javascript

I came across this sorting of an array and I do not understand the compare function at the point where '-1 : 1' is included.  Please can some one explain to me what the compare function is doing exactly?

```js
const rows = [
  createECG('ad0917d4-e02d-4c46-a5aa-dd83717684e9', '28/06/2022', 'pending'),
  createECG('9034124a-2ac8-4d52-8711-ef1351a5c18a', '18/05/2022', 'complete'),
  createECG('a2a7a1f4-81a0-4b70-b1e2-ee7a384a1f4f', '01/05/2022', 'pending'),
  createECG('e5427e62-5897-4eee-a6a6-8f9925feef96', '21/04/2022', 'complete')
].sort((a) => (a.status === 'pending' ? -1 : 1)); // The object 'a' has a property called 'status'

console.log(rows);

function createECG(id, date, status) {
  return {id, date, status};
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comparison function returns `-1` if the first argument `a` as lower than `b` if its status is `pending`. This indicates that `a` is lower than `b`, so it should be sorted ahead. The intended result is that all the `pending` elements will be at the front of the result.

But this isn't really valid, because the comparison function is required to be consistent -- if `a` is lower than `b`, then `b` should not also be lower than `a`. When it's comparing two pending objects, it will return `-1` when they're passed in either order. The comparison function should return `0` in this case, but it doesn't.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take the delta of the comparison for a symmetrically sorting.

```js
function createECG(id, date, status) {
    return { id, date, status };
}

const
    rows = [
        createECG('ad0917d4-e02d-4c46-a5aa-dd83717684e9', '28/06/2022', 'pending'),
        createECG('9034124a-2ac8-4d52-8711-ef1351a5c18a', '18/05/2022', 'complete'),
        createECG('a2a7a1f4-81a0-4b70-b1e2-ee7a384a1f4f', '01/05/2022', 'pending'),
        createECG('e5427e62-5897-4eee-a6a6-8f9925feef96', '21/04/2022', 'complete')
    ]
    .sort((a, b) => (b.status === 'pending') - (a.status === 'pending'));

console.log(rows);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorting is just like filtering, your code means... When
a.status === 'pending'
equal to 1, means this item has the status property set to pending, and when it equals -1 means the status is not set to pending, then as 1 is correct and superior then Items with pending status will come first